# Use interrupts in i2C between Ardiono and Raspberry Pi

Tags: i2c, arduino, c++

I'm really new to `Raspberry Pi` and `Arduino programming (+ I2C)`. Recently I start working on a project where I have to connect an Arduino and a Raspberry Pi to send and receive data from each other.

I'm using `Wire.h` to handle I2C from the Arduino end. Hence it has `Wire.onReceive()` and `Wire.onRequest()` methods, I can specify two methods to act as trigger methods. But I've having a trouble in implementing such kind of methods.

I need to implement a method (on `Raspberry Pi`), which will be invoked only when the Arduino sends some data (some kind of an interrupt). I need this to be written in `C/C++`, since I already have some other functions (using `OpenCV`) implemented.

Any ideas or suggestions to achieve this task ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use I2C.

The standard Raspberry Pi Linux I2C driver can only act as a master device.  It can not deal with unsolicited I2C messages.

Use the serial link instead.  On the Pi end that is /dev/ttyAMA0.  The Pi's gpios are 3.3V so use a voltage divider on the Arduino TX/Pi RX line if you are using a 5V Arduino.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

I'm currently using the `Raspberry pi` to do the processing, which acts as the master. But the problem is, if I'm using serial comm at Raspberry end, I have to keep listening to the port to see if it receives any data. And also, I have to change the code of Arduino to do the same. Wouldn't it be expensive?

Comment: Your choice.  I2C will not work.  Serial will.  Serial data is buffered at the Pi end.  Poll for serial data regularly.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Joan's comments.
The serial has a large buffer (about 200 bytes I think), so you can poll it infrequently. About once per second has minimal impact on processor.

You may be interested in a function `serialGets` I wrote for the Pi.

The available libraries have serial read, but there is no equivalent of `gets` to read a line of data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringSerial.h>

#define MAXLINE 20

int serialOpenB (const char *device, const int baud, const int n)
{
    struct termios options ;
    int fd = serialOpen(device, baud);
    // Get and modify current options:
    tcgetattr (fd, &options) ;

    options.c_lflag |= ICANON;  // set canonical mode (line by line)
    options.c_iflag |= IGNCR;   // ignore CR on input
    options.c_cc [VMIN] = n-1;  // return if n-1 bytes received
    options.c_cc [VTIME] = 0;   // no timeout

    tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW | TCSAFLUSH, &options) ;

    usleep (10000) ;    // 10mS

    return fd ;
}

/* Get a newline-terminated string of finite length.
*********************************************************************************
 */

char * serialGets (char *buf, const int n, const int fd)
{
    int m;
    m = read (fd, buf, n);
    if (m != n) {
      *(buf+m) = '\0';
    return 0 ;
    }
    return (buf) ;
}

int main ()
{
  char line[MAXLINE] ;
  puts("SerialTest\n");

// Always initialise wiringPi. Use wiringPiSys() if you don't need
//  (or want) to run as root

  wiringPiSetupSys () ;
  int fd = serialOpenB("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600, MAXLINE);
 for(;;) {
    serialGets(line, MAXLINE, fd);

    time_t ctm = time(NULL);    // log time
    struct tm *ltime = localtime (&ctm);
    char tbuf[20];
    strftime (tbuf, 20, "%F %T", ltime);
    puts(tbuf);

    puts(line);
    }
  return 0 ;
}
```